# When I import a shapefile in ArcGIS Pro it is in read-only mode

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-pro

I am trying to append many shapefiles together in ArcGIS Pro using the Append function from the Data Management Tools. When I try and run the append I get the error

> ERROR 000262: Target Shapefile is read-only.  Failed to execute (Append)."

The shapefile in question is editable in the "List by editable table" in the contents page. I already removed and reimported into the project, which did not fix the problem.  The solution that Esri gives is,

> Solution:
> Using your operating system tool, check the file properties of the target dataset and turn off the read-only property.

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Open Windows Explorer (the file manager), right click the shapefile files, click Properties, in the General tab, ensure Read-only is unchecked.

Comment: The read-only tab was not checked and I am still getting this error.